# How to select a tool and it's Mode/properties, by hotkey?

Tags: python, 3d-view, shortcut

Is it possible to select **and setup** a tool, by hotkey, or from python ?

For example :

Keymap.py

```
("wm.tool_set_by_id",
    {"type": 'BUTTON4MOUSE', "value": 'ANY'},
    {"properties":
        [("name", 'builtin.select_circle<<<< (wait_for_input="False", mode="SUB") >>>>'),
        ],
    },
)
```

(the example target is a Select Circle -Operator with Subtract -Mode)

Comment: Hello :). Like this? [How to activate different tool gizmos with shortcuts?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/207490/78972)

Comment: @JachymMichal see any Keymap file and https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html , to understand what the example code shows .

Comment: Oh, I don't speak python, that's why I asked :). If the linked thread doesn't help, please edit your original question so it's more clear. Otherwise you risk it being closed by our moderators.

Comment: @JachymMichal i fixed the title, it was made incorrect by other user .

Comment: Sorry, it was me. Does the linked answer provide an answer to your question ? Is your "or" inclusive or exclusive ? Because you don't need python to add a tool or any of its mode to a custom shortcut. (right click > Add shortcut on the icon)

Comment: @Gorgious the shortcuts in Toolbar (your "modes") is not a Modes which you can find on the Tool Settings pane or a code, including the provided example . "and" is an inclusive version of "or" X| .

Comment: So, if I understand right, what you call "Tool" is a blender operator ? The answer is the same, Press F3 for the search operator, type in the name of the operator, right click, assign shortcut

Comment: @Gorgious You are right about the "tool" (world standard) -'s name in Blender . But my answer is the same too X) , the Operators grouped on Toolbar is not an Operator's Modes .

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/196483/86891 ?

Comment: @Gorgious edit: +"as i wrote in the example : builtin.select_circle Operator has SUB (subtract), and p.s. also Extend and Set, Modes ." _ _ 
If i understand correctly . The answer in the topic describes: how to create a shortcut for an Operator, from python, without setting up Modes . In the example case, we have builtin.select_circle that we would put instead of the object.simple_operator , but it wouldn't make the Subtract selection Mode selected after using the hotkey .

Comment: Imagine all the time neither of us would have wasted had you included this in your question ! :) Short answer is, you can't since this operator, as you can see in the docs you linked, does not have a "mode" parameter. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoPgy.png

Comment: @Gorgious this applies only to wm.tool_set_by_id , which is not the target at all, its just a 1 way of selecting an active tool . thanks if you are trying to help, but you don't seem to follow the theme at all . _ _ when you select a tool, it restores the previously set Mode and other settings, instead of using default, so they even more probably can be selected by code . _ _ all the explanations beyond the topic description is excessive .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to [Enable/disable 3D cursor tool properties from python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/178959/enable-disable-3d-cursor-tool-properties-from-python)

You can set the active tool using [`bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name="builtin.select_circle")`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html#bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id) and use `ToolSelectPanelHelper` class to get a reference to it. Code based on *Operator Simple* template:

```
import bpy
from bl_ui.space_toolsystem_common import ToolSelectPanelHelper

class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Set the cursor tool
        bpy.ops.wm.tool_set_by_id(name = "builtin.select_circle")
        # Get the tool
        tool = ToolSelectPanelHelper.tool_active_from_context(context)
        props = tool.operator_properties('view3d.select_circle')

        # Print all properties
        print (dir(props))
        # [...'mode', 'radius', 'rna_type', 'wait_for_input', 'x', 'y']
        
        # Set the properties
        props.mode = 'SUB'
        props.radius = 50
        
        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

    # Add a shortcut
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(
            SimpleOperator.bl_idname, type='C', value='PRESS', ctrl=True, shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

    # Remove the shortcut
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to enable the *Cirle Select* along with your custom tool settings (`mode` and `radius` in this case).

Comment: Thank you . So it can't be achieved without python ? That feature should be (added) in Keymap .

Comment: I don't think a feature like this should be added. I have a feeling that the percentage of people who might need a feature like this is astronomically small and there are plenty of features way more important waiting to be added - just my opinion... But that small percentage of people can always ask for help from the community and get exactly what they want like in this instance. This is a very nice script and a very nice answer!